# Passing code to PyLint as string

Tags: c#, python, .net, pylint, python.net

I am in a situation where I have python embedded in a XPDL file. I'm trying to write a program run PyLint on the embedded python code.

Currently I'm writing the python to a file, then passing that file as the argument to PyLint. I'm writing thousands of small files to disk and immediately reading.

If there any way I could get around writing to disk as it is slowing the process down quite a bit and I haven't been able to isolate if it's PyLint running slow or all of the disk I/O.

I'm using C# with .NET 4.0 to write this.

Thank you!

Comment: you can embed python in C# using pythonnet and then call pylint from C# `using (Py.GIL()) { dynamic pylint = Py.Import("pylint"); pylint.lint.Run(new string[] {"myfile.py"}); }`